# Button on FragmentActivity not working

Tags: android, android-button, android-fragmentactivity

Today I try create a project with fragment activity. I have a MainActivity extent FragmentActivity. MainActvity has layout.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#000" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout have 2 buttons, and a FrameLayout for replace Fragment in here. In MainActivity onCreate I insert a fragment.

**MainAcivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Button", "click--------------");
            }
        );
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

When I insert a fragment into R.id.frame_layout then I try touch button1 but it not response. I can't see it in logcat

Please help me! Thanks

Comment: If you comment out this line //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit(); and does the button click work?

Comment: One tip - its not good idea in general to chain your code.

Comment: @Vinothbabu when i comment it, the button click working.

Comment: What is fragment there? I don't see any code related to fragment instance. // //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: @Vinothbabu fragment in here is a simple MyFragment extent Fragment class, it has a simple layout with a TextView

Comment: @TuanDinh: can u post your fragment class?

Answer (score 1):

in fragments use this :

your XML :

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="yourmethod"
            android:text="Login" />
```

your code :

```
  public void yourmethod(View v){
    //dosomthing 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for support! I try this. It throw error. Can not find method "YourMethod"

Comment: put the yourmethod(View v) in the activity, not the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to,

```
    Button btn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      Log.e("Button", "click--------------");

            }
        });
```